# Is it possible to use PowerMock to mock new file creation?

Tags: java, powermock

I want to cover a logic, that creates files with unit tests. Is it possible to mock File class and to avoid actual file creation?

Comment: This is a good question. Does not deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: Did you try it using PowerMock? PowerMock does mock new object creations inside the method so should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mock the constructor, like in this example code. **Don't forget** to put the class that will invoke the "new File(...)" in the **@PrepareForTest**

```
package hello.easymock.constructor;

import java.io.File;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({File.class})
public class ConstructorExampleTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testMockFile() throws Exception {
        // first, create a mock for File
        final File fileMock = EasyMock.createMock(File.class);
        EasyMock.expect(fileMock.getAbsolutePath()).andReturn("/my/fake/file/path");
        EasyMock.replay(fileMock);

        // then return the mocked object if the constructor is invoked
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[] { String.class };
        PowerMock.expectNew(File.class, parameterTypes , EasyMock.isA(String.class)).andReturn(fileMock);
        PowerMock.replay(File.class); 

        // try constructing a real File and check if the mock kicked in
        final String mockedFilePath = new File("/real/path/for/file").getAbsolutePath();
        Assert.assertEquals("/my/fake/file/path", mockedFilePath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

try PowerMockito

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;


@PrepareForTest(YourUtilityClassWhereFileIsCreated.class)
public class TestClass {

 @Test
 public void myTestMethod() {
   File myFile = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);
   PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myFile);
   Mockito.when(myFile.createNewFile()).thenReturn(true);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I have had such a requirement, and I solved it by creating a `FileService` interface. So instead of creating/accessing files directly, you add an abstraction. Then you can easily mock this interface in your tests.

For instance:

```
public interface FileService {

    InputStream openFile(String path);
    OutputStream createFile(String path);

}
```

Then in your class using this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private FileService fileService;

    public MyClass(FileService fileService) {
        this.fileService = fileService;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // Instead of creating file, use file service
        OutputStream out = fileService.createFile(myFileName);
    }
}
```

And in your test

```
@Test
public void testOperationThatCreatesFile() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockFileService);
    // Do your tests
}
```

This way, you can even mock it without any mock libraries.

Comment: Correct. When you cant mock, wrap it in an abstraction (interface) and then mock it.

Comment: But then you are changing the real code to help the tests, it is good and possible to avoid this with EasyMock/PowerMock

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueRodriguez Yes, you are. And that's a good thing. Writing code that is testable (often) reduces coupling in your code. You should consider the test code to be a part of your architecture.

Comment: But even a loosely coupled code will need something more powerful than this. If you need to test the FileServiceImpl behavior, for example, you will need to mock the File constructor anyway.

Comment: Sure, I see your point, and I was generalizing. However, at that level I would consider verifying it with an integration test instead, as I would do for a class that does database operations. After all, creating and/or verifying a file is pretty straight forward even without mocking.